# rtk query компилятор typescripta ругается на getCurrentUserFavoritesMovies endpoint на queryFn

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { token } from "../env";
import { ResponseMoviesType } from "../types/responseAllMovies";
import { ResponseMovieType } from "../types/responseMovie";
export const moviesApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "moviesApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://api.kinopoisk.dev/v1.4/movie/",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      if (token) {
        headers.set("X-API-KEY", `${token}`);
      }
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getMovies: builder.query<ResponseMoviesType, string>({
      query: (titleFilm: string) => {
        return `/search?page=1&limit=10&query=${titleFilm}`;
      },
    }),
    getMoviesById: builder.query<ResponseMovieType, string>({
      query: (id) => `${id}`,
    }),
    getCurrentUserFavoritesMovies: builder.query<any, string[]>({
      queryFn: async (
        moviesId,
        _queryApi,
        _extraOptions,
        baseQuery
      ) => {
        if (!moviesId) return;
        const results = await Promise.all(
          moviesId.map((id: string) =>
            baseQuery(`https://api.kinopoisk.dev/v1.4/movie/${id}`)
          )
        );

        const merged = results.map((result) => result.data);
        const errors = results
          .filter((result) => result.error != null)
          .map((result) => result.error);

        if (errors.length > 0) return { error: errors };

        return { data: merged as ResponseMoviesType[] };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useLazyGetMoviesQuery,
  useGetMoviesByIdQuery,
  useGetCurrentUserFavoritesMoviesQuery,
} = moviesApi;
```

сама ошибка:

```
Type '(moviesId: string[], _queryApi: BaseQueryApi, _extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: string | FetchArgs) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>>) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(arg: string[], api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: string | FetchArgs) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>>) => MaybePromise<'...'>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ error: (FetchBaseQueryError | undefined)[]; data?: undefined; } | { data: ResponseMoviesType[]; error?: undefined; } | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<any, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ error: (FetchBaseQueryError | undefined)[]; data?: undefined; } | { data: ResponseMoviesType[]; error?: undefined; } | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<QueryReturnValue<any, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = { error: (FetchBaseQueryError | undefined)[]; data?: undefined; } | { data: ResponseMoviesType[]; error?: undefined; } | undefined, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { '...'; } | '...' 1 more '...' | undefined) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<'...'>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 |...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = QueryReturnValue<any, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: QueryReturnValue<any, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<'...'>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<'...'>) '...''.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type '{ error: (FetchBaseQueryError | undefined)[]; data?: undefined; } | { data: ResponseMoviesType[]; error?: undefined; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<any, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<any, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>'.ts(2322)
endpointDefinitions.d.ts(49, 5): The expected type comes from property 'queryFn' which is declared here on type 'OmitFromUnion<QueryDefinition<string[], BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, never, any, "moviesApi">, "type">'
```